# Several Leaderbords in sandbox mode

Tags: ios, swift, game-center

I have created 4 leaderboards for my app. One of them is default. 
I am using 3 different sandbox users. Scores are uploaded without errors. But there is a strange issue. Only default leaderboard contains all 3 scores from 3 users. Others contain 1 score from the active (logged in) user. When I log with another user, I get 3 scores from default board and only 1 score (his) from the other 3 boards.
So each user only see his own score in non-default boards. And my app receives only one score as well.
Is it a glitch or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well seems that there is a lag (1-2 days) while boards have this problem. After some time passes all leaderboards behave as intended.

Answer (score 0):

you probably created leaderboard after creating some of the users. it happens to be all the time. dont't try to delete the user to solve it!! otherwise you will get login popup on your testing device forever. Create new users to test the leaderboard you already created, it will display the accurate submitted information.

Comment: It seems that is not the case. I just created another user. And now I have 4 scores in the default scoreboard and only his on the other 3.